# How to dynamically resize UITableViewCell height

Tags: iphone, uitableview, resize, uitextview

I have the classical grouped UITableView with editable UITextViews inside every cell. This text views can be single or multi-lined, and I want the cell to increase its height as the user writes and the text starts a new line.

My question is: **do I need to reload the whole table just to increase the height of a cell? Isn't there any other method?**

I've been searching a lot, and previous answers and tutorials just talk about how to calculate text height, how to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath... things that I already know. My concern is that, to achieve what I want, I will have to calculate height and reload the table every time the user enters a new character, which I don't find very clean or efficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You do not always have to reload the entire table.  You can instead just reload that one row.

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have another problem now: I just want to reload that row to increase its size, I don't want the cell content to be instanced again. However, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customid" only starts reusing after second call.

What could I do?

Comment: @rickharrison actually you can, check out my answer below.

Comment: It's doing the job really nice, but the cell's content grows respectively. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I'm having a big problem with this... I have a TextField in my cell and calling reload(anything) will cause my textfield to resign first responder status. Any ideas?

Comment: Programmatically save your IndexPath of your row and set becomeFirstResponder to your TextField

Comment: probably best just to add beginUpdates and endUpdates since thats technically what you need to add as well

Comment: @Sn0wfreeze thats not a good recommendation, you can get the indexPath of the cell from the textField alone http://stackoverflow.com/a/27938042/1652402

Comment: The similar solution is to call `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` for the same `indexPath` [(see details here)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37623597/2066428)

Answer (score 94):

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: give it a try, this code forces UITableView to reload cell sizes only, but not cell contents.

Comment: While this basically works, it does not produce as smooth of an animation if you grow the cell as reloading the cell with an automatic row transition.

Comment: Great.. Use it along with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths if you want an animation at some of your rows.

Comment: I added this code in 'shouldChangeTextIn'. and works fine. But not working for new line, and it grows after type a character

Answer (score 27):

To be more specific, yes, you have to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to calculate the new height, then do as rickharrison says and call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation]`. Lets say your cells can have an expanded height and a normal height, and you want them to grow when tapped on. You can do:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath 
{
    if ([expandedPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        return 80;
    } else {
        return 44;
    }
 }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    [expandedPaths addObject:indexPath];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` did not resize the UITableViewCell height, even after I changed the Cell's frame. It only worked when I followed it with a `-reloadData`:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Maybe you were referencing the wrong indexPath, if you debug the application you clearly see that after you call tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPath: the method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath is in fact called.