# UITableView reloadData causes UITextField to resignFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a textField that is set to change the tableView's dataSource with each letter that's entered (and call reloadData).

But for some reason, every time a letter is entered, the keyboard is dismissed.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Post some code of the methods for beginning the editing of your text field and any other relevant methods, we can't help you if we can't see what the problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView reloadData resigns first responder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409370/uitableview-reloaddata-resigns-first-responder)

Comment: @CodaFi you nailed it. The textField was in a custom cell at the top of the table so when I reloadData it reloads that cell too thereby resigning anything inside it. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I will put it up as the answer for you to accept.

Comment: Try the approach explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462473/468868

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your text field is resigning because reloaded cells are sent a `-resignFirstResponder` message due to the fact that their survival is not guaranteed after a reload.  See this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409370/uitableview-reloaddata-resigns-first-responder) question for more.

Comment: A nice workaround is adding a hidden textfield to the view, and switching focus over to that textfield when reloading the table. After the table is reloaded, you can switch the focus back to your original textfield, to keep that keyboard open.  

    [self.fakeTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];

Answer (score -6):

Use this method `textFieldShouldReturn:` and add `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate in yourClass.h file. set delegate to yourTextfield and write following code in `viewDidLoad` method.

`yourTextfield.delegate = self;`

and also implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` as following as

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

   return YES; 
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.