# First tap to the second UITextfield located inside tableviewcell didn't start editing (display cursor). Only the second tap works. Why?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell and three textfields inside. I click the fist one (is called "target") and input some number. The keyboard is displayed which could be dismissed by tapping Done button on the keyboard itself (resignFirstResponder() is attached to Done button).

When I try to edit the second textfield (is called "actual") without keyboard dismissal the cursor doesn't appear on my first tap to the textfield which means editing didn't start (image 1 below). I need to tap this textfield for the second time for the cursor to appear (image 2 below).

How can I make the cursor appear by the first tap to the second editing textfield?

And I do not want to hide my keyboard (launch resignFirstResponder()) when a user decides to continue input let say 4-5 fields in a row. So editing in a textfield should end and start when a user taps another textfield. He edits whatever textfields he needs and then hits Done on the keyboard at the end.

(In fact the cursor  in the second textfield appears by the first tap if a user tapped first textfield but inputted nothing)

My code:

I highlight / dishighlight  the border of editing textfield:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // highlight textfield when editing
{
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    return true
}



func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool  // hide  highlight textfield when editing
{

    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    return true
}
```

I assign text before input to a variable which I check later to prevent data processing if a user didn’t change the text:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) // remember number before user input to prevent actions when no input
{
    textInEditField = textField.text!
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    if  textField.text == textInEditField // no actions if field is empty or text is not changed
    {  
        return
    }

  … inputed text processing
}
```

What I tried:

1. tourchesBegan. But I read that it is used for plain view and doesn’t
   work with scrollview which is my case with tableview

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event:
   UIEvent?)
       {
           self.view.endEditing(true)
       }
   ```
2. to put textField.resignFirstResponder() to the
   textFieldDidEndEditing(). I know I don’t want the keyboard to be
   dismissed when a user edit the second textfield by I tried just to
   check if it works.
3. There is a solution how to dismiss keyboard on touch to the
   tableview background. But actually I do not need keyboard to be
   dismissed cause the user continue editing another textfields.
   [Dismiss keyboard by touching background of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview/4132774#4132774)

[The first tap on the second textfield doesn't show cursor][2] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4voz.png 
    [The second tap on the second textfield shows cursor][3] [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l82A5.png

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the solution.

In `textFieldDidEndEditing()` function I had `tableView.reloadData()`. So the sequence of operations was the following:

1. A user touches textfield1 and does editing. The following functions are fired behind the curtain for the textfield1: `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()` > `textFieldDidBeginEditing()`
2. A user touches textfield2. The following functions are fired behind the curtain:

   for the textfield1: `textFieldShouldEndEditing()` > `textFieldDidEndEditing()` > `tableView.reloadData()`

   for the textfield2: `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()`

The fact that `tableView.reloadData()` was run in `textFieldDidEndEditing()` of the textfield1 was the reason why `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` of the textfield2 was not fired and editing session has not been started. `TableView.reloadData()` launches `resignFirstresponder()`.

To overcome this behavior your need to make textField2 becomeFirstresponder before `TableView.reloadData()` and after. Here is the code

```
    textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
    tableView.reloadData()

    let delayInSeconds = 0.1

    let popTime : dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        {
            nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
```

Here is the answer that helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462473/5826451

Comment: I had a similar problem in a project I inherited, only instead of 2, it took 4 taps! Making it `becomeFirstResponder` solved the issue for me