# reloadData in textFieldDidBeginEditing keyboard not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have textfield in every row of tableview. click on textfield

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

method called but keyboard not appear. I have written

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

in the method.

Keyboard appear if I remove      `[tableView reloadData];` this

any solution ?

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: are you using simulator or real device?

Comment: @Milan Nosal real device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no additional code needed for this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409370/uitableview-reloaddata-automatically-calls-resignfirstresponder#6410851

Comment: @iPatel I believe it somehow. but in my case if I call first responder from cellForRowAtIndexpath then it become deadlock calling each other.

Comment: You need to manage it's time means then your table reload is completed then you use becomeFirstResponder to open your keyboard

Comment: but again when I called first responder manually as per you suggestion with timer it called textFieldDidBeginEditing and reloadata and it's deadlock

Comment: Calling reload on `tableView` lead to`endEditing` method, that why you keyboard close. my suggestion is to avoid table view reload in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` or put it under some condition.

Comment: forget about reload , I have change image of button from textFieldDidBeginEditing without reloadData  also minimize keyboard. any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView reloadData automatically calls resignFirstResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409370/uitableview-reloaddata-automatically-calls-resignfirstresponder)

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the property **KEYBOARD** ? By selecting tableview and in attribute inspector set Keyboard property to do not dismiss and try

Answer (score -3):

press cmd+K from keyboard if you are using simulator.

Comment: OP used real device