# How to adjust the height of the cell table when loading from the custom cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am loading a `UITableView` from 3 types custom `cells`. I made 3 custom classes for that and added all the elements Programmatic by using layout `subview` method. But the issue is all the 3 has a text view in it. it can be variable. after that text view content I need to add a button and a `label`. That I can do, but how to increase the size of the cell according to the content view size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically resize UITableViewCell height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069339/how-to-dynamically-resize-uitableviewcell-height)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the custom cell height will be the same as table view each cell height.

You can use following function to adjust table view's cell height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return height;
}
```

You can use code like this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Defination *definition = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *detailString = definition.detailString;
    CGSize detailSize;
    detailSize = [detailString sizeWithFont:fontSize(12.0) constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(420, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return detailSize.height + 20.0;
}
```

Comment: that i know,i need how to add the height here by checking the text view contents

Comment: i am not at all getting u?wat is this?

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate height by using below function

```
-(CGSize)SizeOfString:(NSString *)string withFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToWidth:(CGFloat)width 
{
    CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 4000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return CGSizeMake(width, size.height + 10);
}
```

Call

```
CGSize size = [self SizeOfString:your_text withFont:your_font constrainedToWidth:width_of_showing_area];
```

Answer (score 0):

ill add another example of measuring a more complex cell.
mind my measurement code isnt 100% correct but it shows the approach

```
+ (CGFloat)calculatedCellHeightForTweet:(id)tweet width:(CGFloat)width {
//text
CGSize s1 = [tweet[@"text"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]]
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

//user
NSString *text;
if(![tweet[@"to_user"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ > %@", tweet[@"from_user"], tweet[@"to_user"]];
else
    text = tweet[@"from_user"];
CGSize s2 = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]]
                      forWidth:width
                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return fmaxf(s1.height + s2.height + /*padding*/ 44, 60);
}
```