# increasing the height of cell loading from a custom class?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to adjust the hieght of the cell table when loading from the custom cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451738/how-to-adjust-the-hieght-of-the-cell-table-when-loading-from-the-custom-cells)

I have an application in which I am loading the cell from different custom class object.It was working fine.But my problem is I am adding a text view on this subclass. I need to adjust the height of the cell in the table view according to the contents of that text view.`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    { 
       return 125;
    }
    else
    {
        return  245;
    }
}
```

Now I am doing like this. But I want the cell height to be changed according to the text view content size in the custom class cell. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can call the cellForRowAtIndexPath: here and calculate the height from the content of the cell.

Comment: it is great if u answer my question

Comment: @Dave there is no need to call cellForRowAtIndexPath, just grab the content and calculate the height. Your way you are creating an extra cell which is not necessary.

Comment: The answer is already been given in you previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451738/how-to-adjust-the-hieght-of-the-cell-table-when-loading-from-the-custom-cells

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in easy way just look at [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell;
  UILabel *label = nil;

  cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:1];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
  }
}
```

then u can Calculate the Cell Height and here an full example [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

  CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

  return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

Comment: did u see the link i'm add ??

Comment: the pbm here is the content text view is not available here.it is in the custom class.

Comment: ok what is the problem it is not deferent plz. explain to me more ??