# Occasional problems with UITableView and heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with rows that dynamically update their height. I have the following method as a delegate of a UITextView in each cell of the UITableView:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
[self resizeRow];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[table beginUpdates];
[table endUpdates];
}
```

This method works fine for updating the table view row height as text is added to the text view. My problem comes when I update a UIImageView that is in the cell to increase its size. This requires a resizing of the height of the cell of the table which works fine, but from that point on whenever the `[table begineUpdates]` `[table endUpdates]` block is called, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of the table view is no longer called. I'm not getting any errors or warnings and have no idea where else in the code to look. My question is then should `heightForRowAtIndexPath` always be called when a `[table begineUpdates]` `[table endUpdates]` block is called or are there cases where this doesn't occur and if so what are they?

Comment: I too had a problem like this but heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called whenever a tableView is displayed does begin and endUpdates will trigger cellForRowAtIndexPath or indexPathsForVisibleRows delegates method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. There was a spurious `[table endUpdates]`; call hidden in a method. This was obviously getting the `[table beginUpdates];` `[table endUpdates];` out of sync in some way. Feel much happier now.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069339/how-to-dynamically-resize-uitableviewcell-height) might help you, but in general `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will get called once when the cell is first displayed or upon a call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`. It might be awkward to make that call from the cell, however, since the cell has no idea of its `indexPath`, but you can get the `indexPath` using a call to `indexPathForCell:`.

Comment: Thanks, my backup plan is to do something like [table reloadData]; and keep adjusting the selected range of the cell so that it stays focussed. This would obviously be quite slow though so if I can get just reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation to work that might be a little less damaging to performance.