# An extra view appears in cell when pressing reorder dragger, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath, reorderlist

I have an `UITableView` with varying height, and when pressing reorder control, in the cell view structure a new view appears. Normally it is not a problem, but sometimes its height is quite big, and it overlaps, with cell below.

- Why this view appears?
- How can I get rid of it?
- Or prevent to overlap other cells?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This view is part of the reorder mechanism and can't be removed. It is used to hide the cell content while you drag a screenshot view above the tableview.

If you set the cell `clipsToBounds` as YES, it should prevent it's content overlapping other cells.