# dynamically resize TableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have four UIView which is placed on UITableViewCell just like
each cell contain one view. And I want to expand the TableViewCell dynamically when click on perticular cell and also adjust following cell.
How it can be done?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: This questions is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069339/how-to-dynamically-resize-uitableviewcell-height

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call `tableView.beginUpdates()`, then call `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(:withRowAnimation:)` on the row index you want to change, and `tableView.endUpdates()`.

You'll also need to implement `tableView(:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`. That should return the 'standard' height for most rows (44.0 by default), and then a larger value for the expanded row.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code:

```
            @implementation ViewController {

                NSIndexPath *indexPathToExpand;
            }

            -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
                 if(indexPath == indexPathToExpand)
                     return expandedHeight;
                 else 
                     return defaultHeight;
            }

           -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
                  indexPathToExpand = indexPath;
                  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }

            @end
```