# How to change the view and at the same time still let the user edit in the TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uitextfield

So I'm having an array of phone numbers and I iterate through it, if one from the array is the same as the one in the textField, I will reload the table row and show some image with number ok and stuff like that. Else let's say if the user now changes that number which was good, like deletes a decimal, now the number no longer matching the ones from the array so I need to change that cell view.But this current code reloading my table for every change in the textField and by reloading it won't stay anymore in editing mode.

```
    @objc func textFieldValueCahnged(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField.tag == 0 {
        if !shouldValidatePhone {
            for phone in self.phoneNumbers {
                if phone == textField.text! {
                   self.phoneNumber = phone
                    GlobalMainQueue.async {
                        self.phoneValidated = true
                       // self.reloadCellForIdentifier("ExtraFieldCell")
                        self.mainTableView.reloadRows(at: [self.rowindexpath!], with: .fade)
                    }
                    break
                } else {
                    GlobalMainQueue.async {
                        self.phoneValidated = false
                        self.phoneNumber = textField.text!
                        self.mainTableView.reloadRows(at: [self.rowindexpath!], with: .fade)
                        // TODO:  IF IT 'S typed a different number that the ones in self.phoneNumbers array we need to update the view with the cell.elementsAreHidden()
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        verifyCode = textField.text!
    }
}
```

the tableView cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhoneValidationCell") as! PhoneValidationCell

                    self.rowindexpath = indexPath
                    cell.label.text = "\(currentField.label):"

                    cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldValueCahnged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
                    cell.sendCodeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendCodeButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

                    cell.textField.tag = 0
                    cell.sendCodeBtn.tag = 0

                    cell.textFieldForVeryfing.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldValueCahnged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
                    cell.verifyCodeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendCodeButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

                    cell.textFieldForVeryfing.tag = 1
                    cell.verifyCodeBtn.tag = 1

                    if self.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
                        if let phoneNumbers = currentField.userPhones {
                            self.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers
                        }
                    }

                    if !phoneValidated && !shouldValidatePhone {
                        if let value = self.extraFieldsValues[currentField.name] as? String {
                            for i in phoneNumbers {
                                if i == value {
                                    cell.phoneVerified()
                                    break
                                } else {
                                    cell.elementsAreHidden()
                                }
                            }
                            if phoneNumbers.isEmpty {
                                cell.elementsAreHidden()
                            }
                            cell.label.textColor = UIColor.black
                            cell.textField.text = value
                            self.phoneNumber = value

                        } else {
                            cell.label.textColor = Theme.placeholderColor()
                            cell.textField.text = ""
                        }
                    } else {
                       // cell.phoneVerified() /// check here
                        cell.textField.text = self.phoneNumber
                    }

                    if shouldValidatePhone && !phoneValidated {
                        cell.phoneToBeVerified()
                    }

                    if phoneValidated && shouldValidatePhone {
                        cell.phoneVerified()
                    }
```

basically when phoe number is in the textField I'm showing `cell.elementsAreHidden()` . when number needs to be validated `cell.phoneToBeVerified()` . and when it s verified `cell.phoneVerified()`

Comment: Why do you reload rows? Did you try just changing them (in main thread)?

Comment: how else will the data change between them, also the heightForRow, cause it's different

Comment: See the last answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069339/how-to-dynamically-resize-uitableviewcell-height might help.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the `indexPath` of the cell you are editing and focus again on it's textfield after the reload by calling `cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()`.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == self.rowindexpath {
        (cell as? ProjectTableViewCell)?.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```